# How can I set touchEvent areas on a TouchImageView in function of a pinchZoom in androidStudio?

Tags: java, android, touch-event

I'm actually programming a mobile application that needs to show up some shapes (rectangles and circles) on an image. I managed to draw shapes on the image, I've added also a zoom system (pinchZoom and double tap zoom) and finally, I've implemented touchEvents on all the shapes drawn on the image.
Here's my problem, when the image is not zoomed, I can tap on the shapes, touchEvents are working perfectly. BUT, when the image is zoomed, the touchEvent areas of the shapes stay fixed at the coordinates of the shapes when there is no zoom... touchEvent areas don't "move" with the zoom in order to stay on the shapes.

Do you have an idea how to fix that problem ?

Comment: see `getImageMatrix()`, you have to apply this `Matrix` (or `invert()`ed one) on your touch points

Comment: ok ! I'm gonna search for that thx !

Comment: s'il vous plaît ;-)

Comment: Ok so I've got the method getImageMatrix() that return super.getImageMatrix(). But where do I use it ? I've got a method contains for the two types of shapes, that return true ou false if the coordinates of the touchEvent are in the shape. Do I ave to use getImageMatrix() here ?

Comment: you have to use it where you get your "touchEvents"

Comment: ok so in my class drawView.

Comment: How can I display code in comments ? ^^

Comment: add it to your question

Comment: Sry I'm trying  to post my code...I'm new to the site ^^

Comment: He says that my code is not properly indented

Answer (score 0):

```
pImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                double x = event.getX();
                double y = event.getY();
                float zoom = pImageView.getCurrentZoom();
                for(int i=0;i<shapes.size();i++) {
                    if (shapes.get(i).contains(x,y,zoom)) {
                        listener.onTouch(shapes.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    return pImageView;
```

Comment: This is my onTouch Listener. I retrieve the coordinates of the touch and then, make an if that check if the coordinates are in a shape which the method contains

Comment: so your `x` and `y` have to be passed to `Matrix#mapPoints`